# Браузер каждый раз запрашивает OPTIONS перед POST запросом?

Tags: api, crud

Браузер каждый раз запрашивает OPTIONS перед запросами GET, POST, PUT ... ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
Про CORS есть куча информации. Если кратко, то «нет», не на каждый. По ссылке выше перечислены условия.